# Delegate not responding to selector

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to pass a NSInteger from a tableViewController (HistoryTableViewController) to another viewController (InformationViewController) but apparently it is not responding to my selector.

HistoryTableViewController.h:

```
@class HistoryTableViewController;

@protocol HistoryTableViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)addItemViewController:(HistoryTableViewController *)controller passItem:(NSInteger *)rowNum;
@end

@interface HistoryTableViewController : UITableViewController {
    NSInteger row;
}

@property (nonatomic, weak) id <HistoryTableViewControllerDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

HistoryTableViewController.h

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    row = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow].row;
   }

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"informationSegue"]) {
   if([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(addItemViewController:passItem:)]){
         [self.delegate addItemViewController:self passItem:&(row)];
        }
    }
}
```

InformationViewController.h:

```
@interface InformationViewController : UIViewController <HistoryTableViewControllerDelegate>
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger rowIn;
```

InformationViewController.m

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"informationSegue"]) {
    HistoryTableViewController *historyvc = segue.destinationViewController;
    historyvc.delegate = self;
    }
}

- (void) addItemViewController:(HistoryTableViewController *)controller      passItem:(NSInteger *)rowNum {
    rowIn = *rowNum;
}
```

"informationSegue" is my segueIdentifier to go from HistoryTableViewController to InformationViewController.

Comment: Which VC is segueing to the other?  It looks like you expect `prepareForSegue:sender:` of the destination VC to be triggered when it is segued to.

Comment: Also, why do you pass a pointer to an instance variable, especially of an `int`?  Why not just pass the `int`?

Comment: I am going from HistoryViewController to InformationViewController. I'm sorry I didn't understand your second question.

Comment: 1) If you're going from History to Information, you never set the delegate.  2) Why is the parameter for `row` in your delegate protocol defined as: `(NSInteger *)` instead of `(NSInteger)`?

Comment: do you know what i should do instead of setting the delegate?

Comment: Setting it is fine; you just have to do so in the correct view controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found out the answer myself. I was using the code for passing the delegate back to another view controller, but I was supposed to pass the delegate forward between view controllers